# How to give more than 3 color in a gradient property such that 2 mixed well in 50% and 1 will show in 50%?

Tags: html, css, colors, background, gradient

I want to give a gradient color to the half side of the background in the 90 degree and white color to another half side. Here is my code

```
body{    
     background: linear-gradient(90 deg, blue 50%, white 50%);
}
```

But here I want to give the gradient color of purple to pink instead of blue. Can I do that? If so then how?

[this is what I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5b8Q.png)

[this is what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwz5Q.png)

Thank You In advance for your help

Comment: I think you need to show an image of what you want to achieve, ideally with sufficient "*[mcve]*" that we can reproduce your starting position. Where did you get stuck when you tried to achieve this?

Comment: i edited the question can you check now

Comment: So this: https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/bmnp3jr7/?

Comment: yes sir  really thank you for you help :D sorry for the bad question 
I am learning to write good question 
Thank you once again :D

Comment: I am not able to ask questions :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this as below:

```
    body {    
      background-image: linear-gradient(90deg,purple,pink 50%,white 50%);
   }
```

Comment: this is the same code i have given can u tell me how can i make the color the gradient color instead of blue?

Comment: Try this : background-image: linear-gradient(90deg,purple,pink 50%,white 50%)

Comment: okay that what i was looking for thank you so much :D

Comment: i can use even 3 colors with this its cooool

Comment: Yep you can and I am glad that you liked it :) :)

Answer (score 1):

You can devide the main div into 2 child divs and then by applying `display:flex` to the main div  or by floating the 2 children(one to left and to right) you can align 2 `divs` side by side and then you can give them background color invidually.

Comment: this is the solution but cant i just change in the gradient directly without really focusing on the div parts

Comment: But it works right, just a little work, But you can do it, (the way you want) just by using css background property and you can put multiple images as well your gradients without playing with the divs. Search the internet and upvote the answer if you like

Comment: well this will work i was just lazy for doing that 
Thank you for the answer buddy really appreciate your help

Comment: Happy to help. Your UI seems good, hope you go a long way